# DaVinci Resolve 18 not importing footage into media library

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am trying to use DaVinci Resolve 18.6 on Linux Mint 21.3 but I am having a rather peculiar issue when trying to add footage to the media storage.  I had rather lengthy footage in *.mp4 format that wasn't even recognized by Resolve (most likely because I am on the free version).  I converted this to *.mov format using ffmpeg and the result (even larger than the mp4) could be imported.

However, it was impractical to work with this huge file. It didn´t seem able to even generate proxies in spite of the resolution of my *.mov files being 720p.

I then resorted to extracing the various segments I was interested in using this ffmpeg incantation:

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i 2015_0101_000056_008.MP4 -c:v dnxhd -vf "scale=1280:720,fps=60000/1001,format=yuv422p" -b:v 110M -c:a pcm_s16le \
-ss 00:01:16 -t 00:00:22 -sn -an -dn footage08_001.mov \
-ss 00:02:07 -t 00:00:30 -sn -an -dn footage08_002.mov \
-ss 00:02:42 -t 00:00:06 -sn -an -dn footage08_003.mov \
-ss 00:32:40 -t 00:00:21 -sn -an -dn footage08_004.mov \
-ss 00:38:43 -t 00:00:32 -sn -an -dn footage08_005.mov \
-ss 00:39:34 -t 00:00:46 -sn -an -dn footage08_006.mov \
-ss 00:40:53 -t 00:00:35 -sn -an -dn footage08_007.mov \
-ss 00:41:42 -t 00:00:11 -sn -an -dn footage08_008.mov
```

I have confirmed that I can watch each of these shorter clips both in VLC and Celluloid.

Now comes the issue: when I try to import these clips (by either dragging&dropping or using the contextual menu "Import Media") only the first one is imported.  I even tried removing the clip that was imported and then manually selecting just the second one but that didn't work. Re-importing the first one again worked fine.

I dumped the metadata for the first two clips but I cannot see anything that would explain why the first one can be imported but none of the others:

```
$ ffprobe -show_data -hide_banner footage08_001.mov
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'footage08_001.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
    comment         : DEMO1
    comment-eng     : DEMO1
  Duration: 00:00:22.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 219975 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 219980 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : FFMP
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 dnxhd
$ ffprobe -show_data -hide_banner footage08_002.mov
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'footage08_002.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
    comment         : DEMO1
    comment-eng     : DEMO1
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7791 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 7785 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : FFMP
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
```

As a matter of fact, I have several original footage that I broke down in the manner described above.  When importing media, only the first clip is ever imported.  So, I could see:

- footage01_001.mov
- footage02_001.mov
- footage03_003.mov

Imported correctly but never:

- footage01_002.mov
- footage02_002.mov
- footage03_002.mov

I searched blackmagic's forum and stackexchange for something vaguely similar to no avail.

It may well be something very silly but I would be really greateful if someone could shed some light in this mystery.